# Display an image from byte array using bitmap

Tags: android, image, bitmap

I have an .txt file with binary data, I put this data in a byte array and im trying to display an image from this array. Im using this code, I know there is a mistake but Im not an expert in bitmap so...

```
FileInputStream inputStream;
OutputStream out = null;

int bytesRead=0;
try{
    inputStream = new FileInputStream(file4.getPath());
    byte[] result = new byte[320*256*2];
    bytesRead = inputStream.read(result);
    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(result, 0, result.length);

    ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageDisplay);

    image.setImageBitmap(bmp);



} catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

}

there is no error in the compilation neither in the execution, but when I click on the button to display the image I have this : `SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null`

Thank you for the help

Comment: `I have an .txt file with binary data`. Dont abuse a .txt file for that. Everybody expects plain text only.

Comment: You could tell how this binary data is encoded. Or show how youdid put it in.

Comment: `SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null`. There is no SkImageDecoder in your code. Only BitmapFactory. So keep to the point please.

Comment: Did you try a file with one image first? Please report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to make this change in your code

```
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(result, 0, bytesRead);
```

Comment: thank you for your response but the problem is still the same

Comment: `inputStream` is correctly opened or is it null? did you set the read file permission in your manifest? Make sure you have added the following permission `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`

Comment: Also check the size of file4 and make sure it's smaller than the buffer length.  If you're thinking that your image is 320x256 so that's what you'll allocate, keep in mind that the size of, say, a JPEG-encoded image stream has a pretty tenuous relationship to the actual number of pixels in the image.

Comment: Actually the size of file4 is 985 513 byte but I want to read only 163 840 byte this is why I am writing byte[] result = new byte[320*256*2];

Comment: Then that's why your decode is failing.  Once the image is encoded into a stream, you pretty much have to read the entire stream.  If you only want a section of the image, you have to decode the entire image, then grab the section of the bitmap that you're looking for.

Comment: I have in my .txt file data for 6 images and 163 840 byte is for one image. So If I read the whole size of my file, I have 6 images as an output.

Comment: Now, if you just want to *down-sample* the image, you can add an options argument at the end of the decodeByteArray arguments. See this: https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

Comment: @Bob, please, note that each image file has some prefix and suffix information stored, for this reason you have to read the whole image data

Comment: im sorry guys, I am not following you. As I said my file contains data for 6 images, and Im trying to display only one.

Comment: I changed the size of my byte array : byte[] result = new byte[(int)file4.length()]; same problem

Comment: `data for 6 images and 163 840 byte is for one image`. There are so many image types. Why dont you tell how you encoded the data?

Comment: `bytesRead` You only read once. What is its value after one read? If it is less than the size of one image you should put the read in a loop until you have all the bytes for one image. Why didnt you tell us the values already?

Comment: I would suggest at this point that you try taking out the buffer and just do `BitmapFactory.decodeFile()` to see if the file itself will decode correctly.